# Calling functions with arguments using bsub command

Tags: python

I am a beginner in the python scripting, I have a script, in which a function is called multiple times, each time with different set of argument passed. The execution is happening in the sequential order. In order to make these run parallel (since there is no dependency while calling these functions), I thought of calling these functions using the bsub command to make it run on multiple machines for faster execution.

```
def func(a,b):
    do_something...
```

bsub -n2 func(A1, B1);

bsub -n2 func(A2, B2);

bsub -n2 func(A3, B3);

I am seeing the below error:

syntax error near unexpected token `('

I also tried using the multiprocessing using 
        from multiprocessing import Process
this resulted in launching multiple jobs on the same machine, which might slow down the execution.

If any of you have better way to do the same, can you please throw some light on the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up Python commands with the commands of your shell. They're not the same thing, so you can't pass a Python function call to `bsub`, nor use `bsub` directly in Python code.

You can probably make a script that calls the function, and use `bsub` on that, but the command line would presumably need to be something like `bsub -n2 my_script.py` (with the function call happening inside `my_script.py`).

Unfortunately, I don't know anything at all about the `bsub` program you're using, so I don't know how you could use it to pass different argument to the script (so that it knows what arguments to use to the Python function). You should probably read its documentation.

It's also possible that there's a Python library available to interface with your cluster architecture. It might be able to run arbitrary Python code for you on multiple systems in parallel.

Comment: I agree there was a mix up of python and shell commands, one more question, in python subprocess.Popen(), we can specify the working directory, where the command need to be run, similar to that is there an option to run the jobs on specific host machines... Like function A is running on machine 'A', function B is running on machine 'B' etc..

Comment: Unless you're using a special library for it, Python will be completely unaware of your different machines. `subprocess.POpen` only works on a single machine, though you might be able to use it to run a command like `bsub` that in turn starts processes on another machine.